# ListAdapter / Cursor, Android. Custom Layout problem

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm experimenting with the Android platform, and I'm beginning to love it, but right now I'm stuck, at this cursor/list adapter problem-thing.
The thing is, that I request a function, returning a data object, with several properties I'd like to map to different TextView's.

My **list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/schedule_item_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
    <TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="1">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:layout_column="1" android:text="teacher" android:padding="3dip"/>
            <TextView android:gravity="right" android:text="Test" android:padding="3dip" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
```

So what I would like to do is: Map a property of an array of objects to several fields in the file. How? Help?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) as your ListView adapter.  It allows you to map a field in your object into a particular widget in your layout.

There are a number of tutorials on this around, for example [my first meeting with simple adapter](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/my-first-meeting-with-simpleadapter.html).